# react-native google map api (android)

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

Well hello first, and then ..
I'm having real issue with the (react-native-maps) component .. I got it all set but when running the app in android i see the blank map with (Google) logo at the bottom of the Blank map  i tryed to use all kind of google maps api (server,android,browser) nothing works ..finlay here is my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="{{my api key here}}"/>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

and thanks,,,

Comment: Have you set correct Google Maps API key in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Additionally, I had same problems with Android 4.x, but not with 5.x+.

Comment: make sure you have correct package name and sha1 key during the api key creation process. this will solve your problem.

Comment: i'll give it a try thx :)

Comment: still blank map with google logo at the bottom of the page , is there anything wrong with my manifest? ..and i don't see any errors in chrome debug :/ ..

Comment: I am facing the same problem, have you figured it out?

Comment: No i did not.. yet :/